# Salesforce for Outlook MFA

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, multi-factor-authentication

in this [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_sales_outlook_integration_2FA.htm) it mentions that starting with Spring 19, " However, the Outlook integration now respects the two-factor authentication that you configure for Salesforce."  Can anyone explain what respects means in this case? Does this mean it wont prompt each time someone opens outlook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Salesforce plugin (app from MS store..) for Outlook which shows Salesforce stuff will prompt for MFA when you connect your Outlook to Salesforce. It previously couldn't do MFA, even if MFA was configured on the Salesforce side.